# R: Read EXIF data from multiple image directories

Tags: r, image, exif, exiftool

I was wondering whether someone has an idea how to read the EXIF data from multiple image directories. I have gathered image data, but for single samples this is often stored in multiple subdirectories. So far, I've tried this:

```
multidirdata <- list.dirs("D:/F04", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

for (i in 1 : length(multidirdata)){
  setwd("C:/exiftool/")
  multisubdirdata <- list.dirs(multidirdata[i])
  for (j in 1 : length(multisubdirdata)){
    filelist <- list.files(path = multisubdirdata, pattern = ".tif", full.names = TRUE)
    fulldata <- data.frame(system('exiftool -FileName -GPSLatitude -GPSLongitude -DateTimeOriginal -,
                              "D:\\F04\\0005SET\\000"', intern = TRUE))
    img.df <- read.delim2(textConnection(fulldata), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE,
                      col.names = c("File", "Lat", "Lon", "Time"))
    setwd(multisubdirdata[j])
    write.csv(fulldata, file = paste("multipts", "csv", sep = "."), row.names = TRUE, append = FALSE)
  }
 }
```

As you can see, this only asks the EXIF data from "D:\F04\0005SET\000" and not from other directories such as "D:\F04\0005SET\001".

Preferably, I'd like to set a vector of all needed image directories through the vectors *multidirdata* and *multisubdirdata*, and use those in the EXIF command.

Comment: You seem to have hard coded "D:\\F04\\0005SET\\000" into your system call and you don't use filelist anywhere so it makes sense that that is all it is doing. You should be able to use `paste0()` to create your call to `system()` for the appropriate file

Comment: Hhave you tried the `exif` or `exifr`-package? If you can make it work, you can use `lapply` to 'loop' thuogh a list of files created with `list.files()`.. google says: https://www.r-bloggers.com/extracting-exif-data-from-photos-using-r/

Comment: Thank you for the `paste0()` suggestion, it seems to work now for one directory, but I haven't been able to loop it back around. I think it might have something to do with the missing ' it needs in the argument.

Comment: I don't know the R language, but one thing to avoid is a loop to run exiftool on every file individually (see [exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/mistakes.html#M3) ), as the startup time is exiftool's biggest performance hit.  You'll get the best performance if you can run exiftool on all your directories at once and then parse the output.

Answer (score 0):

Paying attention to the Common Mistake that StarGeek mentioned made it work for me now:

```
setwd("C:/exiftool/")
fulldata <- system('exiftool -FileName -GPSLatitude -GPSLongitude -DateTimeOriginal -ext tif -r. "D:\\GIS\\Congo\\F04"', intern = TRUE)
```